# Series convergence problem for positive x

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Having the following sequence:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+2\right) \ldots \left(x+n\right)}$  $x>0$

how to investigate its convergence? Which criteria should be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Gauss's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html)...

EDIT: One thing you can do with more elementary methods is to decide the cases $x=1$ and $x=2$, where the summand simplifies nicely, and therefore (using comparison test) $x \le 1$ and $x \ge 2$.

Comment: Alternative method, i am not very fluent at using this thest and still it is beyond the material i am required to acquire.